# How to get text/range at a point in an Outlook Inspector?

Tags: winapi, outlook, ms-word, vsto

I want to know the text at a point in for example an Outlook email.

In Excel and Word I am able to get the ActiveWindow.  Both object models offer the RangeFromPoint method which I have working.

In Outlook the Applicaion object does have a ActiveWindow but it returns either an Explorer or Inspector object.

Further I tried the following code, however it seems the disabled Word Application object in Outlook does not offer the RangeFromPoint.

```
Dim ins As Outlook.Inspector = olMail.GetInspector
Dim wDoc As Word.Document = ins.WordEditor
Dim w As Word.Window = wDoc.ActiveWindow
Dim rng As Word.Range = w.RangeFromPoint(mousePosition.X, mousePosition.Y)
```

I am assuming that Outlook's object model will not help me.

Are there any other methods in the Word Document object model that helps me out?

If the Word Object model does not help must I rely on WinAPI?
If I must use the WinAPI what steps do I need to take?

For example;

- Convert Screen point to a window point of the window holding the text (body of the email)
- get the text at this point.

What is the best WinAPI to get the text at a point in a Window.  Is it to SendMessage with EM_GETSEL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a few things here.

**Why I want to know the text at a point.**
I am building custom tooltips into office.  When the mouse hovers over a point (through the use of the winapi function TrackMouseEvent) I receive from Windows the point where the mouse is.  I then need to know in Outlook (Explorer / Inspector) what the mouse is over.

**First Thought - Outlook and Word Object Model alone.**
As you can see in the question my first thought was to use the same Window object you can use in Word and implement the RangeFromPoint method.  But MS decided to not support this in Outlook.  So this is a dead end.

The second option here was to use either or both of these

```
Selection.Information(Word.WdInformation.wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)
Selection.Information(Word.WdInformation.wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
```

and / or

```
Selection.Information(Word.WdInformation.wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToTextBoundary)
Selection.Information(Word.WdInformation.wdVerticalPositionRelativeToTextBoundary)
```

Vertical relative to page always returned -1 even when the text was clearly in view.
The Relative to Text Boundary returned numbers and they changed with positions but I did not work out where the Boundary was when in the Outlook Inspector.  Margins did not help me.  This could be a way to do this but i did not work it out.

**IUIAutomation or Automation**
I have no experience with these however my attempts to get the TextPattern failed on Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2010.  I name these versions because I found questions here reporting that they were successful with 2013.  I think MS at the time intentionally tried to hide the body of the email to stop ummm slow down email viruses.

**WinApi**
The text body of the email is in a window of Class _WwG and the contents of the window is not visible.  You get "message" as the text.  Seems here too MS did this intentionally.  Thus trying to get the text at a position is not going to work.

**Combination of WinApi and Word Object Model**
The solution that I found which works with the Explorer reading panes and with all inspectors is to use a combination of the WinApi and Word.

- Receive a mouse hover event with point in a window (_WwG Class for Outlook)
- Use SendMessage and send a messsage to this window with the WM_LBUTTONDOWN flag.
- Get the Word Document from the Inspector.WordEditor method.
- The current Range selected will be where the mouse is located in the text.
- Expand the range to the word or whatever you need and now you have what is under your mouse.

For read only windows in Outlook there is no caret visible to the user but it still exists and can be found and used.

I have not implemented this on Outlook items that are being drafted (Cursor is in use and visible), but I suppose I will have to move the selection to the mouse position and then move it back to be able to implement it.  I could imagine this is not the best for some users.

**Edit**
There is one issue with this that I could not solve. By sending a click to the window, you click on what is at that point. If there is a hyperlink there, which is the case with email addresses in a mailItem then it follows the hyperlink. I could not work around this issue properly.  The only thing I did find in the WinProc was that when the mouse is over a hyperlink then Outlook shows a tooltip and there is a WM_USER + 2 message.  Listen for this message and do not click if this message is received.